# Printing Pytorch Tensor from gpu, or move to cpu and/or detach?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm starting Pytorch and still trying to understand the basic concepts.

If I have a network `n` on the GPU that produces an output tensor `out`, can it be printed to stdout directly? Or should it first be moved to the cpu, or be detached from the graph before printing?

Tried several combinations below involving `.cpu()` and `.detach()`

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(5, 10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(10, 10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(10, 3),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)


device = torch.device("cuda:0")  # assume its available
x = torch.rand(10, 5).to(device)
net = Net().to(device)

# Pretend we are in a training loop iteration

out = net(x)
print(f"The output is {out.max()}")
print(f"The output is {out.max().detach()}")
print(f"The output is {out.max().cpu()}")
print(f"The output is {out.max().cpu().detach()}")

# continue training iteration and repeat more iterations in training loop
```

I got the same output for all 4 methods. Which is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not get surprised by the same value output. It shouldn't change anything value.

`cpu()` transfers the tensor to `cpu`. And `detach()` detaches the tensor from the computation graph so that autograd does not track it for future backpropagations.

Usually `.detach().cpu()` is what I do, since it detaches it from the computation graph and then it moves to the cpu for further processing. `.cpu().detach()` is also fine but in this case `autograd` takes into account the `cpu()` but in the previous case `.cpu()` operation won't be tracked by autograd which is what we want. That's it. It's only these little things that are different - value would be same in all cases.